# how can I handle <>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String][]?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to access a List which I return from method.

But I got Error

> Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined,

when I debug my code I got return value in Variable result like **<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String][]**, so how can I handle and use return value which I have returned from method?

```
$('#DTAttendance tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
     var aData = oTable.fnGetData(this);
     var lectureid = aData[0];
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '@Url.Action("GetStudentList", "Attendance")',
         contentType: "application/json; charser=utf-8",
         data: JSON.stringify({ 'lectureid': lectureid }),
         success: function (result) {
            if (result != 0) {
              var dynhtml = "";
              $.each(result.allrecord, function (i, item) {
                dynhtml += "<tr><td>" + item.sid + "<td><td>" + item.sname + "<td></tr>"
            });
            dynhtml = "<table>" + dynhtml + "</table>";
            $("#dttable").html(dynhtml);
           }
          else {
            alert("Some error");
               }
           }
    });
  });
}
```

GetStudentList Function

```
 [HttpPost]
 public object GetStudentList(Int32 lectureid)
   {
    try
      {
        object allrecord = _IAcademy_Repository.GetStudentRecordAccordingAttendanceWise(lectureid);
        return allrecord;
      }
    catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("\nMessage ---\n{0}", ex.Message);
        return 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use `return Json(allrecord);` in your `GetStudentList()` method. Then specify the `dataType: 'json',` ajax option, and access the items using `$.each(result, function(..`

Comment: Thank You Stephen Muecke

Comment: Yes, That will be also work for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in your controller side

```
[HttpPost]
        public object GetStudentList(Int32 lectureid)
        {
            try
            {
                object allrecord = _IAcademy_Repository.GetStudentRecordAccordingAttendanceWise(lectureid);
                return Json(allrecord);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nMessage ---\n{0}", ex.Message);

                return 0;

            }
        }


// And You Should Place 



$.each(result, function (i, item) {
                            dynhtml += "<tr><td>" + item.sid + "<td><td>" + item.sname + "<td></tr>"
                        });
```

Comment: `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is a bit pointless (its a POST). And better to return a Http error or null if there is an exception