# LINQ result (multiple columns) bind to comboBox, then get only one column for SelectedValue

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ to retrive the StationID & Name to bind to a comboBox,

```
var stationId = stationBll
  .GetStations(true)
  .Select(t => new { 
     StationID = t.StationID, 
     Name = t.Name })
  .ToList();

cbMachine.DataSource = stationId;
cbMachine.DisplayMember = "Name";
cbMachine.ValueMember = "StationID";
```

So when i want to get the ID from the selectedValue(), it assigns the whole thing like { StationID: 1, Name: xxxxxx }
How can I get only the StationID, and not the whole thing? 
Please kindly see the attached image, thanks!

```
var StationId = cbMachine.SelectedValue;
```

[image]

Comment: so the selectedValue is your Object or Class.

Comment: You just need to cast it to that , then pick out the id...

Comment: The selectedValue is my comboBox, "cbMachine"

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913187/how-can-i-handle-f-anonymoustype02system-int32-system-string

Comment: nope, it's different from my case

Comment: Hi, are you sure the `ValueMember` is set correctly? Because I'm getting `int` containing the value of the `StationID` property of the `SelectedItem` as expected. Also I guess the question is specific to WinForms combo box data binding and not LINQ, so you might consider changing the tags.